# Ошибка при работе с сокетами: unresolved external symbol impWSASocketW@24

Tags: сокеты, winsock, c++

Здравствуйте! Пишу приложение, осуществляющее работу с raw-сокетами...
Вот код:

```
#include <Winsock2.h>//Ws2_32.lib
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
/*****************************************************************/
void ShowError()
{
        LPVOID lpMsgBuf = NULL;
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER|FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,NULL,WSAGetLastError(),
                MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL,SUBLANG_DEFAULT),(LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,0,NULL);
        CharToOem((char*)lpMsgBuf,(char*)lpMsgBuf);
        cout<<(LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf<<endl;
        LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
}

USHORT checksum(USHORT *buffer, int size)
{
    unsigned long cksum=0;
    while (size > 1){
        cksum += *buffer++;
        size  -= sizeof(USHORT);   
    }
    if (size){
        cksum += *(UCHAR*)buffer;   
    }
    cksum = (cksum >> 16) + (cksum & 0xffff);
    cksum += (cksum >>16);
    return (USHORT)(~cksum);
}
/*****************************************************************/
typedef struct ip_hdr
{
        unsigned char    ip_verlen;
        unsigned char    ip_tos;
        unsigned short   ip_total_len;
        unsigned short   ip_id;
        unsigned short   ip_offset;
        unsigned char    ip_ttl;
        unsigned char    ip_protocol;
        unsigned short   ip_checksum;
        unsigned int     sourceIP;
        unsigned int     destIP;
}IP_HDR;

typedef struct udp_hdr
{
        unsigned short   source_port;
        unsigned short   dest_port;
        unsigned short   udp_len;
        unsigned short   udp_sum;
}UDP_HDR;

/*****************************************************************/

int main()
{
        WSADATA            wsaData;
        struct sockaddr_in remote;
        IP_HDR                 ipHdr;
        UDP_HDR                udpHdr;
        unsigned short     iTotalSize,iIPSize,iUdpSize, iUdpChecksumSize,ver;
        char                       buf[4096],*ptr,szMessage[4068];
        strcpy(szMessage,"Code by Lazy_elf");

        if(WSAStartup(0x0202,&wsaData)){ShowError();}
        else
        {
                cout<<"WSAStartup - OK"<<endl;
                SOCKET sckt;
                sckt = WSASocket (AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,IPPROTO_UDP,NULL,0,0);
                if(sckt == INVALID_SOCKET){ShowError();}
                {
                        cout<<"Raw scoket is created"<<endl;

                        BOOL opt = TRUE;
                        if(setsockopt (sckt,IPPROTO_IP,IP_HDRINCL,(char*)&opt,sizeof(opt))==SOCKET_ERROR)
                        {ShowError();}
                        else
                        {
                                cout<<"setsockopt - OK"<<endl;
                                iTotalSize = sizeof(ipHdr)+sizeof(udpHdr)+strlen(szMessage);
                                iIPSize    = sizeof(ipHdr)/sizeof(unsigned long);
                                ver = 4;
                                ipHdr.ip_verlen    = (ver<<4) | iIPSize;
                                ipHdr.ip_tos       = 0;
                                ipHdr.ip_total_len = htons(iTotalSize);
                                ipHdr.ip_id        = 0;
                                ipHdr.ip_offset    = 0;
                                ipHdr.ip_ttl       = 128;
                                ipHdr.ip_protocol  = IPPROTO_UDP;
                                ipHdr.ip_checksum  = 0;
                                ipHdr.sourceIP     = inet_addr("10.10.10.1");
                                ipHdr.destIP       = inet_addr("10.10.10.2");
                                //-------------------------------------------//
                                iUdpSize = sizeof(udpHdr)+strlen(szMessage);
                                udpHdr.source_port = htons(3004);
                                udpHdr.dest_port   = htons(4004);
                                udpHdr.udp_len     = htons(iUdpSize);
                                udpHdr.udp_sum     = 0;
                                //-------------------------------------------//
                                iUdpChecksumSize = 0;
                                ptr = buf;ZeroMemory(buf,4096);
                                memcpy(ptr,&ipHdr.sourceIP, sizeof(ipHdr.sourceIP));  
                                ptr              += sizeof(ipHdr.sourceIP);
                                iUdpChecksumSize += sizeof(ipHdr.sourceIP);
                                memcpy(ptr,&ipHdr.destIP,sizeof(ipHdr.destIP));
                                ptr              += sizeof(ipHdr.destIP);
                                iUdpChecksumSize += sizeof(ipHdr.destIP);
                                ptr++;iUdpChecksumSize += 1;
                            memcpy(ptr,&ipHdr.ip_protocol,sizeof(ipHdr.ip_protocol));
                                ptr              += sizeof(ipHdr.ip_protocol);
                                iUdpChecksumSize += sizeof(ipHdr.ip_protocol);
                                memcpy(ptr,&udpHdr.udp_len,sizeof(udpHdr.udp_len));
                                ptr              += sizeof(udpHdr.udp_len);
                                iUdpChecksumSize += sizeof(udpHdr.udp_len);
                        memcpy(ptr,&udpHdr,sizeof(udpHdr));
                                ptr              += sizeof(udpHdr);
                                iUdpChecksumSize += sizeof(udpHdr);
                                for(unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(szMessage); i++, ptr++)
                                        *ptr = szMessage[i];
                                iUdpChecksumSize += strlen(szMessage);
                                udpHdr.udp_sum =  checksum((USHORT *)buf, iUdpChecksumSize);

                                ZeroMemory(buf,4096);ptr = buf;

                                memcpy(ptr,&ipHdr, sizeof(ipHdr)); ptr += sizeof(ipHdr);
                                memcpy(ptr,&udpHdr,sizeof(udpHdr));ptr += sizeof(udpHdr);
                                memcpy(ptr,szMessage,strlen(szMessage));

                                remote.sin_family      = AF_INET;
                                remote.sin_port        = htons(4004);
                                remote.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.10.10.2");
                                if(sendto(sckt,buf,iTotalSize,0,(SOCKADDR *)&remote,sizeof(remote))==SOCKET_ERROR){ShowError();}
                                else{cout<<"sendto - OK"<<endl;}
                        }

                        if(closesocket(sckt)== SOCKET_ERROR){ShowError();}
                        else{cout<<"closesocket - OK"<<endl;}
                }

                if(WSACleanup()){ShowError();}
                else{cout<<"WSACleanup - OK"<<endl;}
        }
        return 0;
}
```

В функции ShowError вылетала ошибка на CharToOem((char*)lpMsgBuf,(char*)lpMsgBuf);
Заменил char *на LPCWSTR: CharToOem((LPCWSTR)lpMsgBuf,(char*)lpMsgBuf);

Появилась другая ошибка: unresolved external symbol **imp**WSASocketW@24 referenced in function _main... Что это за ошибка? Как ее исправить?

Comment: Чем Вы транслируете? `#include <iostream.h>` -- откуда? Из бабушкиного сундука? После исправления на <iostream> и добавления `using namespace std;` компилятором i686-w64-mingw32-g++ (GCC) 4.6.3 собралось без проблем (с ключиком -lws2_32). В работе не проверял, для raw socket надо привилегии рута, а нафига мне?

Comment: Извиняюсь, иострим в проекте правильно написал а здесь с ошибся с .h (в вопросе поправил)... и  using namespace std; тоже добавлял... Компилирую в мшыгфд ыегвшщ 2010...

Comment: @Alerr, я понимаю, что Вы уже разобрались, а я только что увидел вопрос.

Но не могу не спросить:  ***а причем здесь raw sockets???***

--

Ведь просто сначала не компилилась (и очевидно в части, не связанной с сокетами), а затем ругань линковщика.

Comment: @Alerr ну вот. `Компилирую в vs 2010...` Тоска. Предыдущее 

     Компилирую в мшыгфд ыегвшщ 2010...

мне больше понравилось.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался с проблемой! Нужно было внести в проект ws2_32.lib.